# Como converter varchar para numeric no SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta SQL, mas ela retorna o seguinte erro: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

```
SELECT Tabela1.CPF, Tabela2.CPF
FROM Tabela1
INNER JOIN Tabela2
ON Tabela1.CPF = Tabela2.CPF
```

Verifiquei que o campo CPF da Tabela1 é numeric e o campo CPF da Tabela2 é varchar. Fiz a conversão do tipo varchar para numeric usando a função CAST(), mas continuei a obter a mesma mensagem de erro: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric.":

```
SELECT Tabela1.CPF, CAST(Tabela2.CPF AS NUMERIC)
FROM Tabela1
INNER JOIN Tabela2
ON Tabela1.CPF = CAST(Tabela2.CPF AS NUMERIC)
```

Por que a conversão não está funcionando?

Comment: Provavelmente você tem algum dado que não é somente números... Por isso desse erro.

Comment: Converta o number para char isto não dá erro , use também um trim , a perfornance deve ser prejudicada.

Comment: Converti numeric para varchar e consegui executar a query com sucesso.

Comment: No conteúdo da coluna CPF de Tabela2 existem somente algarismos ou algarismos e "." e "-"?   Poste amostra dos dados...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com certeza no tabela onde o CPF é do tipo varchar existe lá algum registo que tenha um valor do tipo não numerico. Preste atenção aos espaços no campo. Você pode fazer uso das funções LTrim() e RTrim() para ter a certeza que os espaços serão eliminados.

```
SELECT T1.CPF, T2.CPF
FROM Tabela1 as T1
JOIN Tabela2 as T2 ON cast(LTrim(RTrim(T1.CPF)) as numeric(11,0))=T2.CPF
```

E outra coisa. Para verificar quais dos seus dados podem apresentar alguma inconsistência, pode usar antes este pequeno truque:

```
SELECT LTrim(RTrim(T1.CPF)),T1.CPF,T1.*
FROM Tabela1 as T1
WHERE LTrim(RTrim(T1.CPF))!=T1.CPF
```

Answer (score 1):

O que está a ocorrer é uma conversão automática de tipo de dados, denominada pela Microsoft de conversão implícita. Detalhes no artigo “[Os perigos da conversão automática de tipos de dados](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/os-perigos-da-conversao-implicita-1/)”.

Você comentou que a coluna CPF de Tabela1 está declarada como *numeric*, mas não esclarece o que significa isto: integer, bigint, numeric(11)?

Eis uma sugestão que converte CPF para texto e acrescentando zeros à esquerda, se necessário:

```
-- código #1
SELECT T1.CPF, T2.CPF
  from Tabela1 as T1
       inner join Tabela2 as T2 
       on right ('00000000000' + cast(T1.CPF as varchar(11)), 11) = T2.CPF;
```

Atento que o predicado de junção ficou *non sargable*. Detalhes no artigo “[Construindo códigos T-SQL eficientes](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)”.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!
Tenta converter os dois para VARCHAR e comparar, provavelmente algum CPF está com caracteres diferentes do esperado.
Caso não dê certo, tente fazer um TOP 10 e verificar se é retornado algum dado.
Por último, pode estar imputando esses valores em tabelas temporárias e comparando posteriormente.
Abs.